# My loop isn't separating the array items that don't match on the other array, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, push

I`m trying to .push() the array items on both arrays, that don't match on each other and then assign it to the new array empty that I've created.. but it just iterate and return 60 items repeated.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm still studying that subject, so I'm sorry if what I am doing is dumb haha

```
const bobsFollowers = ['James', 'Caleb', 'Rita', 'Samantha'];
const tinasFollowers = ['Maurice', 'Caleb', 'Samantha'];
const mutualFollowers = [];
const notMutualFollowers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++) {
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]) {
      mutualFollowers.push(tinasFollowers[j]);
    }
    for (let x = 0; x < tinasFollowers.length && bobsFollowers.length; x++) {
      if (bobsFollowers[i] !== tinasFollowers[j] && tinasFollowers[j] !== bobsFollowers[i])
    notMutualFollowers.push(bobsFollowers[i], tinasFollowers[j]);
    } 
  }
}

console.log(mutualFollowers);
console.log(notMutualFollowers);
```

Comment: `x < tinasFollowers.length && bobsFollowers.length;` is sticking out to me. If the lengths are greater than 0, then they are truthy, but not numeric and thus not comparable to `x`.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be using `x` for something in that second inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing that is.
Ojs: I like define a const like currentValue just to make more sense and make understanding easier.

```
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++) {
  const currentName = bobsFollowers[i];
  let isHaveSomeInArray = false;
    
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++) {
    const currentComparation = tinasFollowers[j];

    if (currentName === currentComparation) {
      mutualFollowers.push(currentComparation);
      isHaveSomeInArray = true;
    }
  }

 if (!isHaveSomeInArray) {
     notMutualFollowers.push(currentName);
 }

}
```